# How does DNA codon (5`-3`) convert to mRNA?

Tags: molecular-genetics

There is a problem I stumbled upon when doing a lesson on molecular genetics (Grade 12 level).

The lesson contains many tables in this format: [image: table]

I don't understand how it got to the mRNA codon considering how RNA polymerase creates mRNA. From what I know already RNA polymerase reads the anti-sense/template strand (`` 3`-5` ``strand) and synthesizes mRNA in a `` 5`-3` `` direction.

For example, using the first column with the DNA codon `` 5`-TAC-3` ``, I would automatically convert it to `` 3`-5` `` complementary anti-sense strand because of the nature of the enzyme. It would be `` 3`-ATG-5` ``. Now using that anti-sense strand I would find the complementary base pairs and the mRNA strand would be `5'-UAC-3'`. This is not consistent with the example given by the lesson. I can understand how to get to the answer (just find the complimentary base pairs of the DNA codon given) but it goes against what I know.

Now if the table said (`` 3`-5` ``) instead of (`` 5`-3` ``) it would make sense. Am I misunderstanding a fundamental concept?

Comment: In addition, I did some research and found this table. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table

With the example I mentioned, Tyrosine would be the amino acid if I was going directly from the DNA codon not methionine.

Comment: The table you reproduced shows the DNA sequence on the *bottom* or _antisense_ strand of the gene, but the 5’->3’ notation refers to the coordinates on the *top* or _sense_ strand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct and the table is wrong. The mRNA will have the same base sequence as the sense DNA strand (with T replaced by U).

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, but would add that — although it is not the poor poster's fault — the term ‘DNA codon’ is non-standard and I can see little point at all in a table of this sort. Perhaps for mRNA codon v. tRNA anticodon, but not for this.